# How to use IP_FILTER with python libtorrent

Tags: python, libtorrent

The question I have is: How can I use ip_filter in libtorrent using the python language.

The goal I am trying to achieve is: Block all IP-addresses (in or out going traffic) using libtorrent ip-filter except for the one’s I allow. Code snippet below is where I try to achieve my goal...

```
class Session:
   def __init__(self)
       self.session = libtorrent.session({'listen_interfaces': '0.0.0.0:6881'}) 
       self.ip_filter = None
   ….more….

   def set_access_rules(self):
       self.ip_filter = libtorrent.ip_filter()
       self.ip_filter.add_rule('0.0.0.0', '255.255.255.255', 1)  # I assume ‘1’ means blocking 
       self.ip_filter.add_rule('172.16.100.36', '172.16.100.36', 0)  # I assume ‘0’ allow, prob. wrong...
       self.session.set_ip_filter(self.ip_filter)
```

The (c source) documentation said:

// Adds a rule to the filter. `first` and `last` defines a range of
// ip addresses that will be marked with the given flags. The `flags`
// can currently be 0, which means allowed, or `ip_filter::blocked`, which
// means disallowed.

ip_filter::blocked <- This is where I get stuck, how do I use/write that in python?

The thing is that if I call ‘handle.get_peer_info()’ I expect only to see 172.16.100.36 but I see all sorts of public addresses… Note: My torrent has no trackers and I configured no trackers elsewhere. Can you maybe give me an example in python how to achieve my goal?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/d33b0506a0f4cd61860fd54864267c82d3e171e3/include/libtorrent/ip_filter.hpp#L273) appears to show that `ip_filter::blocked` is simply `1`.

Comment: could you extend your example to be complete? e.g. do you call `set_access_rules()` ever? how do you call `get_peer_info()`? Which version of libtorrent are you using?